# Use HTTP preload with EventSource/Server Sent Events?

Tags: javascript, http, http-headers, eventsource

I have a page that immediately starts streaming events upon load, via an [EventSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource). To speed up the start of that stream, I'd like to use HTTP preload meta tags. But when I add this to my page:

```
<link rel="preload" as="fetch" crossorigin="crossorigin" href="http://myeventsource" />
```

Chrome warns me:

> A preload for 'http://myeventsource' is found, but is not used because the request headers do not match.

Which is true: the preload has an `Accept` header of `*/*`, while the EventSource-originated request has an `Accept` header of `text/event-stream`. The reading I've been doing suggests that the content of that header is controlled by the `as` parameter in the meta tag, but as far as I can see there is no eventstream-specific value.

Is there any way for me to override the `Accept` header it's sending?

Comment: did you make any progress on this?

Comment: No, as best I can tell it isn't possible right now. An alternative is HTTP2 push, I haven't investigated it too much but it might be worth a look.

Comment: See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=962642